# no he podido con este problema de python

Tags: python

Moon ama mucho los numeros de la suerte. Todo el mundo sabe que los numeros de la suerte son numeros enteros positivos cuyo registro decimal contiene solo los dígitos de la suerte 4 y 7. Por ejemplo, los números 47, 744, 4 dan suerte y 5, 17, 467 no.

dado un numero determina si es un numero de la suerte, si el numero es de la suerte imprime "Felicidades tu numero es de la suerte", si no lo es imprime "Tienes mala suerte!"

intente haciendo esto, pero revise y también puede ser 74, ahí es donde quede enredado

```py
numero=input("ingrese un numero")

print(numero.count("47")>0)
```

Comment: no es una tarea, son ejercicios de practica y no he avanzado con este, por lo menos puedo recibir una idea de como hacerlo

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: `all([x == 7 or x == 4 for x in str(numero)])` retorna `True` si los todos los digitos de `numero` son 4 o 7. Sólo te falta agregar un `if`.

Comment: voy a buscar que hace la función all

Comment: graciassss a todos, estoy comenzando con esto de la lógica de programación

Comment: No es garantía que un número que tenga 4s y 7s sea un número de la suerte. Por ejemplo 471 no es de la suerte. **Lo que tienes que hacer es ver qur los dígitos del número sean solo 4 y 7.** Si no lo habías pensado ya te di una pista por dónde empezar. Dale algunas vueltas a eso, escribe un código que se acerque al resultado y la pregunta estará en condiciones de ser respondida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo una cadena la puedes recorrer caracter por caracter con

```
for car in numero:
```

Dentro del ciclo tienes en `car` el dígito a examinar. Con un `if` pruebas la condición, y si no la cumple, terminas con fallo:

```
if car != '4' and car != '7':
    print("No es un número mágico")
    break
```

Si termina todo bien, sin encontrar ningun dígito fuera de orden, puedes procesar la condición con un `else` fuera del `for`.

```
numero=input("ingrese un numero")
for car in str(numero):
    if car != '4' and car != '7':
        print("No es un número mágico")
        break
else:
    print("Es un número mágico")
```

**Versión pitonica**

```
numero = input("Numero")
if all([x == '7' or x == '4' for x in numero]):
    print("Es un número mágico")
else:
    print("No es un número mágico")
```

La comprensión de listas es una forma compacta de escribir el `for` de la primera versión. Esto produce una lista con `True` y `False`. El `True` es cuando encuentra un dígito 4 o 7, y el `False` para otro valor.

La función `all()` retorna `True` si todos sus argumentos lo son. En este, retorna `True` si todos los digitos son 4 o 7.

Comment: muchísimas gracias, la de all la omito porque no he llegado a esa parte pero la primera es justo lo que me decía un amigo que hiciera, descomprimir la cadena y después verificar que los valores sean de la suerte, un abrazo.